# Using jQuery plugins

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-ui, requirejs, require

I am trying to use some of the jQuery plugins in my project (I am using RequireJS). However I don't understand how to do it. I have tried to follow this: http://requirejs.org/docs/api.html#config-shim After what I understand it sets up a dependency of whats inside the array. I thought I could do this in a module:

```
define(['ui'], function($) {

}
```

However it does not work. What am I missing?
This is from my require.config:

```
shim: {
        'ui': {
            'deps': ['jquery']
        },
        'tools': {
            'deps': ['jquery', 'ui']
        }
}
```

and paths;

```
'paths': {
    'jquery': 'lib/jquery/jquery',
    'ui': 'jquery/jquery-ui.min',
    'tools': 'jquery/jquery.tools.min',            
},
```

Comment: have u defined paths for ui and tools in config

Comment: Ah, it seems to be working, you must just specify the dependency and use the `$` as normal.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
requirejs.config({
'paths': {
    'jquery': 'lib/jquery/jquery',
    'ui': 'jquery/jquery-ui.min',
    'tools': 'jquery/jquery.tools.min',            
},
    shim:{
        'ui': {
            'deps': ['jquery'],
            // exports :'ui'   As they are jquery plugins they will not require exports
        },
        'tools': {
            'deps': ['jquery', 'ui'],
             //exports : 'tools'
        }
} 
});

define(['jquery'], function($) {

}
```

Comment: Could you explain `exports`, and `init` in shim?

Comment: exports are used to make the module name available to other modules that are dependent on it .It used for non-amd modules. init function are called before module name is exported .used generally to do cleanup,like calling noConflicft() to avoid overriding a module name already present

Comment: Where do I use these module names? Is it the same as the module ID in `definition`s

Comment: so if I add export to `ui` with `exports: 'test'` then I would require 'test'? But why do I specify `ui` in the dependency list, or would this also change then?

Comment: Inside shim for tools in dependecy list it will be still 'ui' because there you'r just asking it to be loaded before tools library is loaded.